# Example of a bijective function that goes from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$?

Tags: functions

I am trying to think of a bijective function that goes from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$ but cannot think of anything.  Does a function like this exist?

Comment: It's a little tricky because it cannot be continuous.  Can you do  a bijection  from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ ?  Will that help with your question?

Comment: He does not want a continuous one

Comment: Simplifying GEdgar's hint, can you think of any bijection from $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ to $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the comments of @GEdgar and @Sangchul, you can easily shift your focus to a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and the problem is much easier:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 &\mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{N} \\
x & \mbox{otherwise } \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you basically take a countable sequence of real numbers containing $0$, such as $0,1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots$.

Then take the mapping $\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ defined as

$x\mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \mbox{if } x=0\\
1/(n+1) & \mbox{if } x=1/n, n\geq 1,\\
x & \mbox{if } x\in A,
\end{array}
\right.$

where $A$ is the set $\Bbb R\setminus\{0,1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$.

So each element $x$ in the sequence is mapped to the successor of the sequence, while each element $x$ not in the sequence is left untouched.